# How to conduct sensitivity analyses for cluster / sample in three-level meta analyses in metafor?

Tags: independence, sensitivity-analysis, metafor

**Problem**
am wanting to do a leave1out sensitivity analysis of an rma.mv (three-level) meta-analysis, where "1" is a cluster / sample (rather than a single effect size).

I understand that some functions, such as leave1out, do not work with rma.mv model objects (e.g., [Metafor package: bias and sensitivity diagnostics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/155693/metafor-package-bias-and-sensitivity-diagnostics?newreg=b31ea762e18b4626a7988a69a19f3589)).

**Attempted solutions**

I do not know how to write a "for-loop" (which Wolfgang suggested in post above), so cannot try that.

I have searched the web, but found no guidance on 'for-loops', nor how to do sensitivity analyses for samples / clusters in a three-level meta analysis.